# How to automatize and rename (according to server date) file download with Wget or Curl

Tags: curl, wget

I have a PDF file that it is published almost everyday (almost) with the same name and the same url.

What I want to do is to:

1. Download the file only if the remote file is updated (this is difficult for me since the file keep always the same name even when is updated, could be possible to check for the file size?);
2. Rename the file according to the date of the server (not my system date: I have 9 hours difference from the server);
3. Automatize the script to check on the file every 12 hours.

PS: I have a Mac, with both `CURL` and `WGET` installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution here is timestamping: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping.html#Time_002dStamping

A cron job set every 12 hours with wget -N should do the trick.  That will check the PDF's headers, see if it's new, and not download if it's not.  Since it'll pull down with the PDF's timestamp, you can write a bash script to take the output of ls -l, look for the mtime, and use that to rename the file.